# Motivic structures on cohomology of function spaces between algebraic varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{C}$. I am interested in the cohomology of $\operatorname{Hom}(X_{top},Y_{top}),$ where I am taking homomorphisms between the underlying topological spaces rather than morphisms of algebraic varieties. Can I naturally attach a mixed Hodge structure to this cohomology?

I don't have a precise formulation of what I want from this mixed Hodge structure; I'm hoping for something like a spectral sequence converging to the cohomology whose morphisms are morphisms of mixed Hodge structures coming from $X$ and $Y$. I am really interested in analogous situations where I am considering some other Weil cohomology theory, but there my question is even less precise.

EDIT: I'm really interested in the case where $X$ and $Y$ are over some finite field, and I want a Galois rep which could be called the cohomology of $\operatorname{Hom}(X_{top},Y_{top})$ (as well as a computational procedure for computing it.) Maybe Jason's suggestion of etale homotopy theory in the comments is the way to go?

Comment: If $X$ is $\mathbb{P}^1$, there is a natural mixed Hodge structure first constructed by John Morgan, with further work by Hain, Deligne, and Navarro Aznar.

Comment: @JasonStarr: Thanks for the references! I vaguely remember you mentioning this to me at some point but couldn't recall what precisely you said. Do you mind me sending you an email with some further details?

Comment: (or why not posting details as an answer, so we can all learn something?)

Comment: @YosemiteSam: I could elaborate, but it concerns a much more specialized question than the one asked here...

Comment: From reading just the introduction to Morgan's paper https://eudml.org/doc/103954, the key point is that the invariants he considers that admit a mixed hodge structure all depend only on the rational homotopy type. Presumably this is not true for the rational cohomology of Hom-spaces unless one considers some kind of rational-homotopy-Hom-spaces?

Comment: @WillSawin: Yes, I was assuming we were talking about the rational homotopy groups.  I do not know if the mixed Hodge structure has an "integral version".

Comment: @JasonStarr Makes sense. I was just thinking more about whether the construction you mentioned generalizes to arbitrary Hom-spaces. I'm saying it can't unless their rational cohomology can be computed from the rational homotopy types of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: This is probably nonsense, but maybe you can use the etale homotopy theory of Artin, Mazur, and Friedlander to reduce to the case where $Y$ is a $K(\pi,n)$.

Comment: @JasonStarr: That might actually be the right approach for what I want; see the edits.

Comment: @dhy I suspect you are right and etale homotopy types are the right way to go about. For schemes $X,Y$ over $k$, the internal homs between the etale homotopy types of $X_{\overline{k}}$ and $Y_{\overline{k}}$ is a pro-object in simplicial sets that admits an action of $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{k}|k)$. Presumably one can take cohomology of this with finite or $\ell$-adic coefficients, giving a Galois representation.